Derivative of normal vector expressed in terms of tangent vector and covector
I am reading the following from a book that $n$ is normal vector, $a_{\alpha}$ is tangent vectors ($\alpha = 2, 3$). Naturally we know
$$n \cdot n =1, n\cdot a_{\alpha} = 0$$
And take variation on those two equations, we have
$$\delta n \cdot n =0, \delta n\cdot a_{\alpha} + n \cdot \delta a_{\alpha} = 0$$
The book says we can solve variation of the normal vector as
$$\delta n = -[a^{\alpha}\otimes n]\delta a_{\alpha}$$
My questions is
How this equation be derived? And how is tensor product got involved?
Thanks!

I assume it should be $\delta n\cdot n =0$?

@NDewolf, yes, you are right. Just updated

Maybe also a relevant question: is (Einstein) summation over repeated indices assumed?

@NDewolf, I will say no summation on $\alpha$. The book doesn’t state it clearly
